# if, else syntax and adding data to a new field

Tags: python, arcgis

I am trying to have this new field, "FERRY", have either "YES" or "NO" depending on criteria from the "FEATURE" field.  I'm using a search cursor to search for road features that have a ferry crossing.  If they do, the "FERRY" field will have a "YES" for that row and "NO" for vice versa.  I can make the new field successfully but when I get into my for loop and if else statement for trying to enter "YES" or "NO", the program doesn't work exactly.  Is there something wrong with the syntax?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "E://fall_2018//Python//Assignments//Exercise6//Exercise07"


fc = "E://fall_2018//Python//Assignments//Exercise6//Exercise07//roads.shp"

fieldname = arcpy.ValidateFieldName("FERRY")
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldname, "TEXT", "", "", 232)

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["FEATURE"], '"FEATURE" = \'Ferry 
Crossing\'')

for row in cursor:
    print row[0]
    if row[0] == "Ferry Crossing":
        delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, "YES")
        cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FERRY"], delimfield + " <> 
        'YES'")

          print delimfield
    elif row[0] != "Ferry Crossing":
        delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, "NO")
        cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FERRY"], delimfield + " <> 
       'NO'")
del cursor
```

Below is the output:
[ouput for the code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Bsr.png)

Comment: if you may include the output, someone can help. `elif row[0] != "Ferry Crossing":` is not necessary. just `else` is good enough (though it's not wrong).

Comment: line `print delimfield` seems to have indentation issue.

Comment: ^ Thank you.  I tried having just the else statement like you said with the update cursor and it still did not work.  My output is essentially just populating that "FERRY" field with "YES" or "NO".  I'm not sure what other output I would generate.

Comment: what do you see on `print row[0]`? Also, you should move `print delimfield` to last line in `for row in cursor` loop. then if you still see issue, please post the output.

Comment: ^  print[row] merely just prints 'Ferry Crossing' for every feature that is a Ferry Crossing.  The output prints that, creates the new FERRY field, but then it doesn't put anything (YES or NO) in the individual rows.

Comment: Based on your output, `if row[0] == "Ferry Crossing":` is not matching (assuming you have `print delimfield` inside the `if`). try `if str(row[0]).strip() == "Ferry Crossing":`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.  What does .strip() mean?

Comment: it will remove characters like `space`, `newline` etc at the beginning and end.